# How to iterate through child objects from JSON API call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, key

I am beginner trying to iterate through the child objects from my API call to obtain the keys from the key-value pairs. So from my state example below, I'd like to be able print "id", "name" and "email" (and eventually use these to populate the 'headers' and 'accessors' in ReactTable to automatically generate my columns. This may be beyond the scope of my question for now).

```
state = {
data: [
       {"id": 1, 
        "name": "John", 
        "email": "john@test.com"
       },
       {"id": 2, 
        "name": "Alex", 
        "email": "alex@test.com"
       },
       {"id": 3, 
        "name": "Sam", 
        "email": "sam@test.com"
       },
       {"id": 4, 
        "name": "Jess", 
        "email": "Jess@test.com"
       }
]
}
```

The keys for all my objects are the same (id, name, email for example). However, I can only obtain the parent key of each of the child objects within the data. In my case, the parent keys just happen to be the index values of the objects within my array. So for the 4 objects as shown above, my console.log output will just be an array of ["0", "1", "2", "3"] since there are 4 objects. Instead, I would like to obtain ["id", "name", "email"]. My code is below. I'm willing to add another nested loop to access the child components, but whatever I do breaks the code.

```
getKeys = () => {
        var keysArr = []
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) { // i < 1 because I only need to access the keys from a single object
            keysArr.push(Object.keys(this.props.data.children)); // The '.children' breaks my code but it is to show that I would like to access the child objects          
        }
        console.log(keysArr)
    }
```

Any help editing my code, or suggesting a new method would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you dont need the for loop. Just change your:

```
keysArr.push(Object.keys(this.props.data.children));
```

to

```
keysArr.push(Object.keys(this.props.data[0]));
```

You can directly access the keys only using:

```
keysArr = Object.keys(this.props.data[0])
```

Your function should be like:

```js
var state = {
data: [
       {"id": 1, 
        "name": "John", 
        "email": "john@test.com"
       },
       {"id": 2, 
        "name": "Alex", 
        "email": "alex@test.com"
       },
       {"id": 3, 
        "name": "Sam", 
        "email": "sam@test.com"
       },
       {"id": 4, 
        "name": "Jess", 
        "email": "Jess@test.com"
       }
]
}
getKeys = () => {
        var keysArr = []
        var i;
        keysArr=Object.keys(state.data[0]);       
        console.log(keysArr)
    }
    
getKeys();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This seems to be work.

However, I'm encountering an unusual quirk. Since I grab my data from an API call, I initialize 'data' as an empty array. When I do this and use the code you showed, I seem to get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

However, if I initialize the data array with some predefined data (like in my original post), and then do the API call to overwrite the data, it seems to work perfectly fine.

I suspect that the getKeys() function is being called before there is any data in the array. Any solution to this?

Comment: Hi @purelife, you can look out for the event thats triggering the getKeys() and then call it only when there is actually a prop object. Like add an if(this.prop && this.prop.data) or something of the same.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
const yourSet = new Set();
data.forEach(obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => yourSet.add(k)))
```

This will loop through every key in your array.  So, if the objects is the array are different all the keys will be picked up.